# Unable to install14.04 on Toshiba Satellite L40D-B

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Brand new Toshiba Satelitte L40D-B
Model: PSKRGC-002001
Windows 8.1 pre installed
64 bit AMD A6-6310 APU
AMD Radeon R4 Graphics
RAM: 6144 MB
Clock: 1.80 Ghz
HDD Toshiba 686 GB
Bios 1.00
English
Trying to install Ubuntu14.04.1 from usb stick (tried several different sticks, checked them)
This is a maintream laptop. I have already install numerous Ubuntu and other distros.
I tried Fedora 20 and Ubuntu 13.10 on this computer with the exact same result:
I have no other computer available, and no cd/dvd

I tried to install with secure boot and UEFI on at first, then turned off secure boot then turned off UEFI

With secure boot and uefi on, the install strarts, then a grub screen asking me to choose between live, install, oem install and check for disk defects. I tried them all repeatedly. The screen goes dark and after 10 seconds, the computer reboot.
with secure boot off and uefi on, same thing
with both swcure boot ad uefi off, first i could go to the language page of the install. Choose english. Then same thing. The computer reboots.
I switched live usb creator (windows) for unetbootin to make usb stick. Same thing except unetboot screen (blue) instead of grub (dark)
I tried then to partition HDD with windows. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this same problem on my HP laptop.First install ubuntu 12.04 with secured boot turned off.You must have to be connected with internet while installing 12.04.So that it can able to download and install new packaged.Unless it shows error in grub install.
After the 12.04 installation is completed you can easily able to upgrade to ubuntu 14.04.
For ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 14.04 upgrade use the below link
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04